# How to access extension configuration options from TSconfig conditions?

Tags: typo3, tsconfig, typo3-9.x

Global extension settings are done in `ext_conf_template.txt` and edited in the BE in the `Settings module`. The documentation headlines this settings as `Configuration options`.

How are they accessible from pageTSConfig conditions in TYPO3 versions 9.x?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not possible with the conditions based on the symfony expression language at the current state.

In the BE I can verify that the access would be via global variables: 
    `GLOBALS|TYPO3_CONF_VARS|EXTENSIONS|myextkey|mysetting`

In the unit tests I found a comment that access to global variables is bad. I conclude that a general access to globals is just not implemented. Instead access to some global variables is provided as functions for example access to TSFE as `getTSFE`.

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Conditions/Reference.html#functions

The drawback is, that the access to many global variables is currently not implemented.